# Checked radio button when "other" textbox is clicked

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have a simple set of radio buttons renders as follows:

```
< div ng-repeat='option in quest.opts' >
                    <input  type="radio" ng-name='{{quest.id}}' ng-model='$parent.$parent.choice.input'  ng-value='{{option}}' id='{{quest.id}}-{{option.id}}' ng-required='required'>
                    <label class="labelStyle ansMargin"  for='{{quest.id}}-{{option.id}}'><span></span>{{option.txt}}</label>
                    <span ng-if='option.id == 999' class="inputMargin">
                        <span ng-click='enableOther(option)' >
                        <input type='text' class="form-control textInputBox" ng-disabled='optOther.isDisabled' ng-required='optOther.isRequired' ng-model='optOther.txt'>
                    </span>
                    </span>
    < /div>
```

option.id 999 is for the other...
Now if i click it normally it's working great, but i want to allow user to click on the other text! input, so what i do right now is ng-click='enableOther(option)' and in the js it goes:

```
scope.enableOther = function(option) {
                        //console.log(option);
                         scope.choice.input = option;
                         scope.otherEnable();
                };
```

The problem is that it enables the other text, but the input radio! button is unmarked...
I don't understand why..

Comment: ng-name is not a angular directive. Is this your own directive?

Comment: yes, this form is created dynamically, it's for interpolation purposes, i tried to do the same without it, it's not because of it

Comment: The following will also be a good answer: How can i manually check the last of the radio buttons in this group...

Comment: could you bring it in fiddle ?